# Complex Numbers expression

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

This question may sound too basic, but I am new to complex numbers.

We all know $e^{it}=\cos t+i\sin t$. Given a real diagonal matrix $P$, what does $e^{itP}$ look like? I am guessing it would be: $e^{itP}=\cos P_{11} t +i\sin P_{22} t$, where $P_{11}$ and $P_{22}$ are diagonal entries. But I am pretty sure my guess is not correct.

Comment: What do you know about $e^{A}$ where $A$ might be a real or complex matrix?

Comment: @BrianBorchers I know we can use taylor expansion to write a complicated formula for it. Also, $e^A$ is in general linear group.

Comment: It's easy to find the powers of a diagonal matrix so you should be able to see what the power series for the exponential tells you.

Comment: @EthanBolker Following your hint, I got $e^{iPt}=I+iPt-\frac{1}{2}P^2t^2\cdots=\cos(Pt)+i\sin(Pt)$. However, $Pt$ is a matrix, not an angle. It does not feel correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's do things using the "complicated formula":
$$
e^{itP} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac 1{k!}(itP)^k = 
\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac 1{k!}i^k t^k P^k = 
\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac 1{k!}i^k t^k \pmatrix{P_{11}^k & 0 \\0 & P_{22}^k} = \\
\pmatrix{\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac 1{k!}i^k t^k P_{11}^k & 0 \\0 & \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac 1{k!}i^k t^k P_{22}^k} = 
\pmatrix{e^{iP_{11}t} & 0\\ 0 & e^{iP_{22}t}}=\\
\pmatrix{\cos P_{11}t + i \sin P_{11}t & 0\\ 0 & \cos P_{22}t + i \sin P_{22}t} = \\
\pmatrix{\cos P_{11}t & 0\\ 0 & \cos P_{22}t}
+ i \pmatrix{\sin P_{11}t & 0\\ 0 & \sin P_{22}t} = \\
\cos(Pt) + i \sin (Pt)
$$

Answer (score 1):

Of course, Omnomnomnom has already given a good answer to your question. Let me replace your question with a slightly different one:

> Calculate $e^{tJ}$ where $J = \left[ \begin{array}{cc} 0 & -1 \\
> 1 & 0 \end{array} \right]$

Then, since $J^2 = \left[ \begin{array}{cc} -1 & 0 \\
0 & -1 \end{array} \right] = -I$ we find $J^3 = -J$ and $J^4=I$. In other words, $J$ behaves as $i \in \mathbb{C}$. Thus, $J^{2k} = (-1)^kI$ and $J^{2k+1}=(-1)^kJ$ so we calculate the matrix exponential as follows:
\begin{align} e^{tJ} &= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(tJ)^{2k}}{(2k)!} + 
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(tJ)^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!} \\
&= \left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^kt^{2k}}{(2k)!}\right)I + 
\left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^kt^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}\right)J \\
&= \cos(t) I + \sin(t)J
\end{align}
In fact, $M_{\mathbb{C}}(a+ib) = \left[ \begin{array}{cc} a & -b \\ b & a \end{array} \right]$ defines the **regular representation** of $\mathbb{C}$. In particular $M_{\mathbb{C}}(1) = I$ and $M_{\mathbb{C}}(i)=J$ and you can verify that $M_{\mathbb{C}}(zw)= M_{\mathbb{C}}(z)M_{\mathbb{C}}(w)$ and $M_{\mathbb{C}}(z+w) = M_{\mathbb{C}}(z)+M_{\mathbb{C}}(w)$. In addition, it's interesting to note:
$$ M_{\mathbb{C}}(e^{it}) = M_{\mathbb{C}}(\cos( t)+i \sin t) = \cos (t) M_{\mathbb{C}}(1)+\sin(t)M_{\mathbb{C}}(i) = \cos( t) I + \sin (t) J.$$
Or, $M_{\mathbb{C}}(e^{it}) = e^{tJ} = e^{M_{\mathbb{C}}(it)}.$ This identity is true for many algebras.

Comment: I think your last expression has an extra $e$ in the exponent.

Comment: I was considering adding something like this given OP's "guess" of the answer, but you did a better job than I would have.

Comment: @mr_e_man thanks, fixed.